# How do i move all the numbers to allign with the columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
CANOEING = 3.5068
HIKING = 6
ROLLER_BLADING = 7.5068
TAE_KWON_DO = 10.3014
TAI_CHI = 3

body_mass = float(input("Enter your body mass: "))
canoeing = 0
hiking = 0
roller_blading = 0
tae_kwon_do = 0
tai_chi = 0 
print("                      Canoeing       Hiking         Rollerblading       Tae Kwon Do           Tai Chi              ")
print("15")
print("30")
print("45")
print("60")
print("75")
print("90")    
for x in range(15,95,15):
    canoeing = CANOEING+body_mass+(x/60) + canoeing
    hiking = HIKING+body_mass+(x/60) + hiking
    roller_blading = ROLLER_BLADING+body_mass+(x/60) + roller_blading
    tae_kwon_do = TAE_KWON_DO+body_mass+(x/60) + tae_kwon_do
    tai_chi = TAI_CHI+body_mass+(x/60) + tai_chi
    print("{0:>31.2f}".format(canoeing))
    print("{0:>36.2f}".format(hiking))
    print("{0:>51.2f}".format(roller_blading))
    print("{0:>61.2f}".format(tae_kwon_do))
    print("{0:>71.2f}".format(tai_chi))
```

How do i align all the answers with the columns ie, hiking and the times like 15 min.
I did what i could but all the answers come all messed up.

Comment: Please post current output and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can only print left-to-right, top-to-bottom. So you can't print all the row headers first, and then print all of the data; you have to print each row headers along with its data.

Also, each of your `print` statements prints a newline. You need to add `end=''` to prevent that.

So, this should get you started:

```
print("                      Canoeing       Hiking         Rollerblading       Tae Kwon Do           Tai Chi              ")
for x in range(15,95,15):
    print('{0:>2}'.format(x), end='')
    canoeing = …
    …
    print("{0:>31.2f}".format(canoeing), end='')
    …
    print()
```

This still isn't going to look right because your format widths are much, much wider than the columns you're trying to fit them into. (Also, since your header is 115 characters wide, it's not going to look very nice in a typical 80x25 terminal window…) But hopefully you can fix that part yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could also fetch all the values into one print/format like:

```
print("                      Canoeing       Hiking         Rollerblading       Tae Kwon Do           Tai Chi")
for x in range(15, 95, 15):
    canoeing = ...
    ...
    print("{}{:>28.2f}{:>13.2f}{:>22.2f}{:>18.2f}{:>18.2f}"
          .format(x, canoeing, hiking, roller_blading, tae_kwon_do, tai_chi))
```